# how to cache html document in AWS

Tags: html, mysql, amazon-web-services, caching, cdn

I am working on a project that let users to create their own web pages. I have two options in my mind store the html code in mysql db, or create html doc in the file systems of the server.

I am looking for speed and efficiently as the html codes will be loaded a lot of times.

my question is what would be the best approach? I will use AWS as cloud. Is there any feature in AWS that can help with caching of html docs? would using CDN can help in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Use S3 for static files(Static web hosting) and use cloudfront for cache.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use [AWS S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html) to store your html files and use [AWS CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) CDN to cache the content at edge locations.

For more details check [Using CloudFront with Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigrateS3ToCloudFront.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own domain and would like to have a valid certificate you could use https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl next you could just store your static page in an AWS S3 bucket, follow this guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

so at the end, you have something like:

```
(internet) ---> cloudflare(CDN + SSL) ---> AWS S3
```

More info also can be found here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-Cloudflare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-